# SQL telling me a column and expression are different data types

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a program in pgadmin 4 using sql and when I try to insert data into a table, the error is telling me “column is of type Boolean but expression is of type integer” when I declared the variable in the create table as a Boolean.

I have no idea where to start

Comment: There are no variables in `CREATE TABLE`. You could start by asking a good question that includes the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements you used.

Comment: At least enter some code snippets explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.